# Facebook Like Button in Iframe Not Showing Up In Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, facebook

It works in Firefox but not in Chrome. The code I have is:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=190148824367454&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fpainlessric.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=144&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:144px; height:90px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I'm pulling my hair out. I added this too:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">

<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Painless Ric&#039;s Tattoo Studio" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://painlessric.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://painlessric.com/painlesslogo.gif" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Painless Ric&#039;s Tattoo Studio" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="170378829657868" />
</head>
```

But still nothing. Here's the URL of the site:
http://painlessric.com/

But (i *did not* build the site, just adding this button) because it's using frames:
http://painlessric.com/main.php?facebook

I added ?facebook for testing. I have some PHP code that checks if `facebook` is set and if so shows it.

If you know of any JavaScript or anything too that'll force it to work let me know.

Comment: Looks the same to me in both Firefox and Chromium. I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: This is what I see: https://skitch.com/oscargodson/fdmb3/mozilla-firefox

Comment: I see the Facebook thing in both Chrome and Firefox. No problems here.

Comment: What OS? Err. Ill check my other laptops

Comment: I see like button in Chromium 11.0.696.65 (84435) Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: I see your like button on chrome 10.0.648.151 WINDOWS AND chrome 12.0.742.91 MAC. So I guess your chrome is the problem !!! Did you try  emptying your caches ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Chrome 16.0.912.77 m.